# React twice mount component, but on second time doesn't receive props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class AsideNav extends Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        navigation: ''
    };
}

componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props.data.navigation); // data from parent received
    this.setState({
        navigation:  this.props.data.navigation.map(function(el, index){
            return(
                <Link key={index} className={"aside-nav__link " + (el.modifier ? ("aside-nav__link" + el.modifier) : '')} to={el.url}>{el.name}</Link>
            )
        })
    })
}



render() {
    console.log(this.state.navigation); // JSX for navigation is ready
    return (
        <nav className="aside-nav">
            <span className="aside-nav__title" >Категории</span>
                {this.state.navigation}
        </nav>
    );
}

}

export default AsideNav
```

After (seemingly) successful implementation of code it displays me an empty block and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined at AsideNav.componentWillMount...

Comment: use componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) to get props second time as constructor and componentDidMount methods get executed only once.

Comment: Actually, your error states that `navigation` is called on `undefined` which implies that `data` that you receive in `props` is undefined. In simple terms, you don't receive `data` in the props.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by rendering twice ?

Comment: I don't understand why it rendering twice. Console.log in my code displaying two times. First time - correct. Second time - error.

Comment: are you updating the props in parent component ?

Comment: No. I don't update it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

**1.** Never store the `ui items` in state variable, always store data only and then generate the `ui` elements dynamically.

**2.** Use `componentWillReceiveProps` method, it will get called if you do any changes in `props` values in parent component, update the `state` value of child component at that time.

**3.** Since you just want to create the items from `props` data, directly use `props`, instead of storing anything.

Write it like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class AsideNav extends Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = { };
    }

    renderLinks(){
        let data = this.props.data;
        return data && Array.isArray(data.navigation) && data.navigation.map((el, index) => {
            return(
                <Link 
                    key={index} 
                    className={"aside-nav__link " + (el.modifier ? ("aside-nav__link" + el.modifier) : '')} 
                    to={el.url}
                >
                    {el.name}
                </Link>
            )
        })
    }



    render() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <nav className="aside-nav">
                <span className="aside-nav__title" >Категории</span>
                {this.renderLinks()}
            </nav>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i see same error again) I tried render component without states (use only props) - same thing. 
Maybe problem there:
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fj9ozz4fyrmc0z/main-content.js?dl=0

Comment: sorry, didn't get this, where is `AsideNav` component, and from where MainContent is getting the props values, can you show the code of Parent component (where u r calling `AsideNav` component)

Comment: did u use this condition `data && Array.isArray(data.navigation) && data.navigation` ?? check the code try to use the same, it should not through this error, n don't use the lifecylce method.can you show the new error that u r getting, other part looks ok.

Comment: Yes. I add "data && Array.isArray(data.navigation) && data.navigation.map" and error disappeared, but my sidebar navigation still contains only title. renderLinks() dont run. It's my console http://i.imgur.com/4bwD5dN.png

Comment: `console` shows that your data is getting changed some how, check the 2nd `console` result it does not contain the key `sidebarContent`, check the parent component of `MainContent` component from where u r passing the `props`, i think there is some issue within that.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vd7ml5jvsqnq83p/page-dashboard.js?dl=0 - it's parent of MainContent. Other pages builded same way, but i did not pass props to Sidebar before.

Comment: sorry dude, the code that u showed looks proper, parent is passing the data child is receiving it properly, not able to figure it out where it is getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

se componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) to get props second time as constructor and componentDidMount methods get executed only once. And also add check if data available or not.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class AsideNav extends Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        navigation: ''
    };
}
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)
{
console.log(newProps.data.navigation); // data from parent received
    this.setState({
        navigation:  newProps.data &&newProps.data.navigation.map(function(el, index){
            return(
                <Link key={index} className={"aside-nav__link " + (el.modifier ? ("aside-nav__link" + el.modifier) : '')} to={el.url}>{el.name}</Link>
            )
        })
    })
}

componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props.data.navigation); // data from parent received
    this.setState({
        navigation:  this.props.data && this.props.data.navigation.map(function(el, index){
            return(
                <Link key={index} className={"aside-nav__link " + (el.modifier ? ("aside-nav__link" + el.modifier) : '')} to={el.url}>{el.name}</Link>
            )
        })
    })
}



render() {
    console.log(this.state.navigation); // JSX for navigation is ready
    return (
        <nav className="aside-nav">
            <span className="aside-nav__title" >Категории</span>
                {this.state.navigation}
        </nav>
    );
}

}

export default AsideNav
```

Comment: its a very bad solution, you should never store ui items in state variable, always store data in state and call a function from render that needs to create the ui for that. He is beginner may be don't know this, since you are providing solution, you should mention that.

Comment: @MayankShukla it is not my solution. I just pointed out his mistake to resolve his issues.

Comment: that is called solution :), you need to either correct what he is doing or mention that in suggestion that you are doing this mistake also :)

Comment: A problem located in root file 'main.js'. I accidentally have mounted two components with common children.   :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


import App from './app';
import PageDashboard from './page-templates/page-dashboard';
import PageRating from './page-templates/page-rating';


import './styles/css/style.css';

//render(<PageDashboard />, document.querySelector('.main-wrapper')); - before

render(  
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        //<Route path="/public/" component={App} />  - before
        <Route path="/public/" component={PageDashboard} />  // -  now
        <Route path="/public/rating" component={PageRating} />
    </Router>, document.querySelector('.main-wrapper')
);
```

A problem located in root file 'main.js'. I accidentally have mounted two components with common children.